# Android 12+: Microphone stops in WebRTC app within a WebView when screen is locked or user switches apps

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, microphone, lockscreen

I'm developing a `WebRTC` voice calling app for Android using `PeerJS`, where all the PeerJS code runs within a `WebView` inside my CallScreen activity. The calling functionality works flawlessly. However, I've encountered an issue specific to `Android 12` and higher devices: the microphone stops functioning as soon as the screen is locked or the user navigates to another app.

I've researched this extensively, and most suggestions online recommend using a `Foreground service` to record audio. Unfortunately, this isn't feasible in my scenario because I'm trying to access the microphone from a `WebView` within an `activity.`

Is there any workaround or solution to resolve this microphone issue on Android 12+ devices while still operating within the constraints of a WebView within an activity? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using a foreground service is the way to go actually. You can access microphone data in the service and then send it to PeerJS webview accordingly.

Comment: How can I send microphone data from service to webview???